# XML parsing error: "Not well-formed (invalid token)", fabiang/xmpp PHP library package with xmpp openfire

Tags: php, xml, xmpp

I've been trying to figure out why I get the "XML parsing error: "Not well-formed (invalid token)" error when trying to "send presence" to my server ( that is running localy on the same machine ), after successfully connecting a user to the server.

Everything is ok, until I try to access `$client->send(new Presence);` method on the client object, after he is connected for example. This is what I get after running `$client = new Client($options);` and dumping the client object that is returned in the process.

**Client object dumped**

[image: Successfull client object]

But, if I run the line of code in my controller that says, for example `$client->send(new Presence);` after that, I get this nasty error

**XML Parsing error**

[image: xml parsing error]

The code in my controller test method is pretty simple for this, just using the guide from the documentation for the fabiang/xmpp package on packagist.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Fabiang\Xmpp\Client;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Options;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Protocol\Roster;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Protocol\Presence;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Protocol\Message;

class XmppController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {



    }

    public function test() {

        $address = "dergree-pc:9090"; // if using HTTP in front, it will give the "cant open stream exception"
        $username = "test";
        $password = "password";

        $options = new Options($address);
        $options->setUsername($username)->setPassword($password);

        $client = new Client($options);

        // ALL THE ABOVE CODE WORKS

        $client->send(new Presence); // this or any other line below gives the XML parsing error
        // optional connect manually
        //$client->connect();
        //$client->send(new Roster);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must be connected and authenticated to the XMPP server before you can send a presence.
Your test function does not call the connect method before you send the presence.

Comment: $client->connect() is just a manual way of connecting, since calling `new Client($options)` does that automatically :)
I've found the issue... It was due to some SSL certificate setting on openfire server. It didn't let the authentication through because of it.
I've disabled SSL ( since this is a testing project anyways ) and enabled TLS ( I think it is what it's called ) and it works :)

Thank you for trying to help out, really appreciated !